# Fire child components function from parent component using a ref

Tags: reactjs, react-native, refs

Morning!

I have a component setup like below (React Native)

I am trying to trigger a function in the class `<Child>` by pressing a button in a sibling component. In the parent component, `<Parent>` I am setting a ref to the `<Child>` component. The ref is always `null` so I am missing something here, but not sure what.

If I attach the ref to another component, say a `<TouchableOpacity>` at the same level in the DOM, the ref exists? I am not sure whether it is because my `<Child>` function is custom or not.

Using RN 0.6.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {

  ...

  fireChildFunction = () => {
    if(!this.childRef) return null;

    this.childRef.childFunction()
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <Parent>
        <Child ref={(ref) => {this.childRef = ref}/>
        <ButtonChild onPress={this.fireChildFunction} />
      </Parent>
    ) 
  }
}
...

class Child extends React.Component {

  childFunction() {
    // do something
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
         ...
      </View>
    ) 
  }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Please read this https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-ref-attribute-dom-node .
I don't think your usecase have to use Ref. U have to use ref when u need to get some attributes from the DOM. so I don't think the child will have the function u need. 

Just passing down the function u need from parent to your child. Or using React Context if u think the props drilling is too much

Comment: I need to access the childs function in the parent component, so I can't pass it _down_ as it were. You may be right though in that my use-case doesn't need refs, but I don't think for the reason you have suggested? I think my issue may be related to redux, and I need to pass `{useRef: true}` in my connect function. Will update the answer once I know! Thanks for your time :)

Comment: When you are trying to access the function of another component, you shouldn't directly jump into using refs.  It is discouraged. Try to use states and props to make your components communicate. If you need to change data in the ```<Child>``` component using the ```<ChildButton>```, you can have a state in ```<Parent>``` and put it to the prop of the child.

Comment: If you are using Redux, you can connect your <Child />  and <ChildButton /> components to the store. Once you press <ChildButton>, it should update the state of the store, which will update the <Child>.

Comment: thanks for replying Fatih, I appreciate I should try and avoid refs. Unfortunately in our case we are triggering an imperative animation, and the benefits of refactoring the code do not outweigh the drawbacks of using a ref!

Comment: Maybe try this ? 
https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-to-dom-components

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below example where we called sibling function with the help of ref.

**Parent Component**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import Child from "./Child";
import Sibling from "./Sibling";

export default class Parent extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.childRef = React.createRef();
    }

    fireChildFunction = () => {
        alert('called from fireChildFunction');
        if (!this.childRef) return null;
        this.childRef.current.childFunction()
    };

    render()
    {
        return (
            <div>
                <Child ref={this.childRef}/>
                <Sibling onPress={this.fireChildFunction}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Child Component**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

export default class Child extends React.Component {

    childFunction = () =>{
        alert('called from childFunction');
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Sibling Component**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

export default class Sibling extends React.Component {

    onClick = () => {
        this.props.onPress();
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.onClick}>Click from Sibling</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Khabir :) This answer is correct, and it was in fact what I was doing. However my mistake was not realising that in using Redux' connect function, I needed to forward the ref to my Child component through the connect function. I have posted an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I am using Redux and when you use the `connect` function it create a HOC wrapper. Therefore the ref was not being assigned to the `<Child>` component. I had to add `{forwardRef: true}` as the 4th argument in the connect function that wrapped my `<Child>` component. Hope this can help someone one day!

for reference:
https://itnext.io/advanced-react-redux-techniques-how-to-use-refs-on-connected-components-e27b55c06e34